# Maze algorithm path finder

Tags: c#, algorithm, graph-algorithm

I am trying to find the path of a maze, below is the code, it suppose to goes inside the recursiveSolve loop but it keep exiting, after second if condition what i am doing wrong here can someone help me please?
im setting Washere and correctpath array as false by default.

```
recursiveSolve(0, 0);

public static int[,] maze = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
                             {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1},
                             {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
                             {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1},
                             {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0},
                             {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}};

public static Boolean recursiveSolve(int row, int col) {
    Boolean[,] wasHere = new Boolean[6, 6];
    Boolean[,] correctPath = new Boolean[6, 6]; // The solution to the maze

    if (maze[row, col] == 1 || wasHere[row, col]) {
        return false;
    }
    else if (row == 0 || row == 6 - 1 || col == 0 || col ==6 - 1) {
        correctPath[row, col] = true;
        return true;
    }
    else {
        wasHere[row, col] = true;
        if (recursiveSolve(row - 1, col) || recursiveSolve(row + 1, col) ||
                                            recursiveSolve(row, col - 1) || 
                                            recursiveSolve(row, col +1)) {
            correctPath[row, col] = true;
            return true; // successfully escaped; this square is on path
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging?  You'd see that your second if condition is true, causing the function to exit.

Comment: Note the condition in your `else if`: `else if (row == 0 || row == 6 - 1 || col == 0 || col ==6 - 1)`, since you call this with `recursiveSolve(0,0)` both the `row == 0` and the `col == 0` conditions are true and you exit the function. Did you not intent to start at the edge of the maze?

Comment: @MattBurland i just through that could be starting point, what what would be the parameter for the starting point?

Comment: @Milas: I don't know, it's up to you to decide how your program should work. Most mazes have one entry point and one exit point. As you have it, any point on the edge is an exit point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wasHere and correctPath arrays are local to the recursiveSolve function, which means each time you enter in this function, the arrays will be inited to false (or random value).

First of all try to make these arrays static as well, and see if that solves your problem with the always false.

Also, you should start your search from somewhere inside the maze instead of from an edge (0,0 means you already exiting the maze).
If you want to start from 0,0 ,mark that as a starting point, and don't allow it as a valid solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you're actually doing path finding and this is not an excercise which requires this particular solution, then you might also want to look into the A* algorithm which is probably more efficient and robust.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm)